# The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I have been getting this error in futter while I was integrating firebase email,password sign up. "The getter  `uid` isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'." not only for `uid` but also for `displayNmae` and `email`. can anyone help me please?

```
void ValidateForm() async {
  FormState? formState = _formkey.currentState;
    Map value;
   if (formState!.validate()) {
       User user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser!;
   if (user == null) {
       firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _emailTextController.text,
              password: _passwordTextController.text)
          .then((user) => {
                _userServices.createUser(
                  user.uid,
                  {
                    "username": user..displayName,
                    "email": user.email,
                    "userId": user.uid,
                    "gender": gender,
                  },
                ),
              })
          .catchError((err) => {print(err.toDtring())});
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          (context), MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => a_n()));
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `user` value is a `UserCredential` object, to get the `uid` you need to access the `user` inside that.

```
  "userId": user.user.uid
```